# jquery/javascript carousel Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am pretty new to jquery/javascript. Can someone please recommend a carousel plugin. So far I have looked jCarousel. It doesn't seem like I can extend this plugin easily as prev/next buttons are rendered for you.

I need a plugin which can directly access the markup(instead of crawling through the dom) and accepts data as parameter, can be extended to show photos in two rows like the below matrices, and renders a previous and next button like below:

1, 1
2, 1

Can someone please recommend one? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bootstrap-carousel](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) was just released as part of Twitter's [Bootstrap 2](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)

Comment: The problem with Bootstrap is that it is for prototyping-only. To implement it into an existing project, it requires one to refactor and adopt their CSS framework/philosophy to use a single component.

Comment: Thanks, we already use bootstrap for other UI functions. This is really cool. We will mostly like pull and mod, only what we need.